# Django if field = blank, set field = 1?

Tags: django, django-models

Can I use conditional statements in my either my models.py or admin.py file to do the following?:

```
if field (trying to be saved) == blank, set field = 1.
```

Thanks for the help. Please ask me to clarify if need be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to override the save method on your model.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # this is your model "trying" to be saved, before the "real"
    # save is called by super below

    if self.field == 'blank':
        self.field = 1
    super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods

If you wanted to do it in your admin.py (so admin specific behavior, not global model behavior), you would want to override `save_model` on your `ModelAdmin`

```
# code mostly from docs
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if obj.field == 'blank':
           obj.field = 1
        obj.save()
```

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model